# How do I capture a single image from webcam and process it further in OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I want my code to capture a single image from webcam and process it further, like later detect colours and sobel edges and a lot more.
In short, I want to do image acquisition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use your webcam, you can use `VideoCapture`:

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) # use 0 if you only have front facing camera
ret, frame = cap.read() #read one frame
print(frame.shape)
cap.release() # release the VideoCapture object.
```

You start the webcam, read one image and immediately release it. The frame is the image and you can preprocess it however you want. You can view the image using `imshow`:

```
cv2.imshow('image', frame)
if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xff == ord('q'): # press q to exit
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) # Usually if u have only 1 camera, then it's 0, if u have multiple camera then it's may be 0,1,2 ...
ret, frame = cap.read() # ret is True or False status which shows if you are success reading frame from web cam, frame is an array
# If u want to loop to read continously
ret = True
while ret:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if frame is None:
        continue # this will stop the loop if we failed to read frame, because ret will be False
```

If this is the answer that u wanted, then it have been asked multiple times. Make sure you have tried to search the answer before you asked

Comment: eh, this is simply to read the webcam. I did not want this, I want my webcam to take up ONE picture (one frame) and process it further through algorithms.

Comment: @bsikriwal You could just `break` after the first loop?

Comment: @MohitMotwani eh well I am new to programming, can you just tell me how it will look like? for real please :)

Comment: @bsikriwal I have answered your question. Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

image = cam.read()[1]

cv2.imshow("image", image)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.